# Bigcommerce how do I use YAML to access all products

Tags: yaml, bigcommerce

In all of the documentation so far, I've seen the code:

```
---
products:
    new:
        limit: (number)
---
```

I don't even see the "new" attribute in the stencil docs nor do I know how it determines which products are new since I don't see any sort of attributes on the bigcommerce site dashboard. https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/product-resources#Product

But, how do I get all of the products and not just "new" products. There are over 45+ different products on this site but when i do

```
{{log products}}
```

I only get back the 'new products'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

New products is a globally available object, but there isn't a way to make all products accessible on the page with front matter.

https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/new-products-object

New products are defined as the most recently added products to your store. Top sellers and featured products are also globally accessible, so a workaround might be to use featured products and set the limit in your front matter to a high value like 100. Then, you could mark every product as featured to surface your entire catalog.

Comment: thanks for replying! I found a slight workabout where I put all my items into a category 'shop'.